# align left to the center box in css

Tags: css

I got something like this:

```
<h3 class="product-name"> Product name </h3>
<dl class="item-options"> some options </dl>
```

H3 is center aligned, is it possible to align item-options to left edge of h3?
So would like this: (product name and options have different lenght)

```
<div style="width:100%">
_____product name long (text align center)_____
     product options
</div>
```

if I put text align on both it will look like this:

```
<div style="width:100%">
_____product name long (text align center)_____
              product options
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the header and dl in a wrapper div and center it like this:

```css
dl, dt, dd {
  margin: 0
  }

.wrap {
  
text-align: center;  
  border: 1px solid #000;  
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
dl {
  
text-align: left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Header with a long string</h3>
    <dl>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd>Definition</dd>
    </dl>
      
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```